# With custom user model 'allauth' does not show username in admin panel as expected

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-custom-user

According to [this official instruction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) I made `custom user` model with `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`. I continue to use `username` field, but as not required. `EMAIL` and `USERNAME` could be different. The problem is that `allauth` in admin panel in the column `USERNAME` shows user's email address.

As a test I did the next:

1. I created 2 users and `allauth` shows identical values for `username` and `email` when they should be different.
   [image]
2. If I change user's email via "Home -> Custom_User -> Users" (`test_user_name@gmail.com` to `CHANGED_test_user_name@gmail.com`), `allauth` at "Home -> Accounts -> Email addresses" shows changed value in `User` column instead of `E-mail address` column.
   [image]

I checked in a fresh installed Django and there everything works as expected.

I expected to get what I need using such `allauth` settings:

```
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
```

but no luck. Also I tried many different settings, but can not fix this issue.

If do not use `username` field at all (remove from models.py + ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None), and if to change user's email, `allauth` does not change its behaviour - keep showing changed email in `User` column, instead of in `Email address` column.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
```